# Proof of (Strong) Markov Property using sigma-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains

I would like to ask if any of you know of a good resource containing rigorous proof (using sigma-algebras) of Markov Property and Strong Markov Property respectively in terms of Discrete Time Markov Chains.

(All resources I have found dealt with Continuous Time Markov Chains or with discrete MP/SMP in terms of Brownian Motion.)

Thanks,
C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varadhan's "Probability Theory" has a proof of the SMP for discrete-time chains.

Comment: You might also want to look at Kai Lai Chung's text as well, which spends some time looking at discrete MC's.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

See Theorem 6.3.4. of *Probability: Theory and Applications (4th edition)* by Richard Durrett.

Also, a very accessible proof is found in Theorem 1.4.2 of [*Markov Chains*](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/) by J.R. Norris.